# Error #1193 MySql, insert trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TRIGGER `UpdateId` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `comments`
FOR EACH ROW
set @vid=(select MAX(comments.id) from comments)+1; 
set new.id=@vid;
```

this query gives me an error #1193 saying id variable is unknown.

Everybody that seemed to have a similar problem was not putting the 'new' clausole before the variable, but in my case it still doesn't work. The 'new' clausole doesn't get highlighted when I type it, it looks like it is not a special keyn word but a normal word instead.

Answer (score 0):

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html, it looks like you might need to either use just one `set` statement or use a `begin ... end` construct. My hunch is that the `create trigger` statement ends at the first semi-colon, and then MySQL doesn't know what you're talking about when it gets to `new.id=@vid;`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `UpdateId` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `comments`
FOR EACH ROW
set 
    @vid=(select MAX(comments.id) from comments)+1, 
    new.id=@vid;
```

OR

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `UpdateId` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `comments`
FOR EACH ROW
begin
    set @vid=(select MAX(comments.id) from comments)+1; 
    set new.id=@vid;
end;//
delimiter;
```